# How do I remove icon overlays from unversioned folders in Tortoise SVN?

Tags: svn, icons

How do I remove icon overlays from unversioned folders in Tortoise SVN?

Comment: Close cross-site duplicate: *[TortoiseSVN file overlay performance - are there any ways of improving it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525829)*

Comment: The above link is missleading since the screenshot is too old. Please refere to accepted answer.

Comment: FYI, The proposed "close cross-site duplicate" is useful if you want *manual* control over which folders do not get icon-overlays. Below answer is simpler, if you want to turn off icon overlay of *all* unversioned files/folders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an option in **TortoiseSVN | Settings | Icon Overlays | Overlay Handlers**. See [TortoiseSVN manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-overlay-handlers) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

**To remove icon overlays, do this:**

> Click on an empty area near that directory path. Right click
>   Tortoise SVN settings, go to Icon Overlay, and uncheck *Show Icon Overlay* for
>   ignored items. It's all done; all icon overlays of the folder are
>   gone.
>
> If it is already revisoned then do this: go to that directory / file.
>   Right click *Properties* of Tortoise SVN. Select the list item "add it
>   to ignore list". Don't be afraid the file won't get deleted!! AND
>   then repeat the above procedure.

Comment: @Danijel did this help to solve that.

Comment: I don't remember. :-( There is no more overlays, but how I resolved it I don't remember since it was a long ago. Sorry.